# Selenium-Find Element by cssSelector

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to Selenium and I am asking your kind advice.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="order">
<a style="float: left;" href="#137674" class="voidCmn ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button">Void</a>
<a style="float: left;" href="printcmn.php?Id=137674" target="_blank" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button"> Print </a>
<a style="float: left;" href="section_a.php?cmnId=137674&amp;origin=viewreferral.php" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget" role="button"> Edit </a>
</div>
```

In that scenario I would like to use cssSelector and not an xpath.

My code to find web element button Edit (see above):

```
Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget[role='button'][href^='viewreferral.php']"));
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget[role='button'][href^='viewreferral.php']"}
```

Could you kindly review and tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below given css Selector, It should work :

```
 a.ui-button.ui-corner-all.ui-widget[role='button'][href*='viewreferral.php']
```

You have used wrong operator to check contains. You used : `^` But it should be `*`

Comment: And if I can ask you one more question, please.  Would it be possible to search by class and the name of the button (see it is not saying "name=…" inside braces <>, but like that …button"> Edit </a>.   Would it be still possible to search by name  of the button ?

Comment: No We can't do that with CSS selector as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you, again.  Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: No Problem. Keep Learning :)

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed an operator to be * (asterisk) and it worked.